# How to debug dll in C++ Builder XE?

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, c++builder

My core project which is a standard windows application is being developed under C++ Builder XE. This project is using dll file written in older version of development environment, namely C++ Builder 6. Application is crashing somewhere inside dll so i decided to debug dll. What should I set to see source code of dll? All I can see is assembler code. It seems like debugger don't see source code directory. I have copied debug symbols file *.tds in the same directory as *.dll it seems it doesnt nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XE cannot debug into the source code of a BCB6 DLL.  You need to use the BCB6 IDE for that instead.  Load the DLL project into BCB6 and set your XE app as the DLL's Host Application in the "Run > Parameters" dialog.  You can then run the project from the BCB6 IDE, which will start the Host app and attach the debugger to the DLL when it is loaded into memory, then you can debug the DLL's source code.

Comment: Thanks. Its acceptable solution even when debugging both XE sources and BCB6 sources would be better.